# Object will not fit curve

Tags: path, curve-modifier

So i habe tried it multiple times, i create a path, make an array of planes and fit it to said path. All good, but when i started to snap loose parts together and fitted the curve afterwards, it would only pick a small part of the entire path.[image]

Next thing on my list is to sperate the entire path into multiple sections, doing that none of the mentioned modifiers work for the sperated piece.[image]

Afterwards i noticed that the track didn`t snap together at all, it just looks like it on edit mode, but in object mode it is a whole different story:[image][image]

If you have any idea on what is going on, pls help me out, because i sure don`t.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Array modifier works only on single curve segment (from curve start to curve end point). Snapping does not connect start/end points of curve. Curve cant share point with more than two splines.

You can try set for curve under properties Geometry > Bevel > Object and select simple straight line (another curve object) ...

[image]

I don't know what will be your next step so ... converting into mesh there will be overlaps ...

[image]

Another way can be convert your curves into mesh, connect what should be connected and try **Skin** modifier ...

[image]

... but also here expect corner issues :)

Probably the best way is to use other software, set stroke, outline and merge ... import as SVG into Blender.

Comment: The problem is, it is allows the same path, i am only extending and snapping different parts of it, so it does not make any sense to me why it would only fit one part of it.

Comment: The array actually matches the snapping of the path, but when i divide the path in 2 sections it all goes out of hand. Suddendly the array only follows some parts of the selected path and othertimes completley different ones.

Comment: Each of your two curve objects consist from several disconnected parts. You can see it if you move cursor above some part and hit L, it will select part of connected control points. Each control point has internal index number (indices) starting with zero. Array starts at curve with control point zero and fills this part up to last connected point. I don't think you can display the indices, but it doesn't solve nothing here, if you still want to use array modifier you would have to separate each disconnected part of curve into solo object with another Plane ...that is tedious  ...

Comment: Tedious but possible, well thank you very much for your help. I will try it out when i got time.